# Помогите решить проблему с кодом на Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

Прошу, помогите найти код в ошибке и решить проблему, а то моя тупая головушка не может понять конкретного места. Прошу, не судите строго, я новичок в Ардуинке.
Код:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

int flag = 0;

LiquidCrystal lcd(13, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7); //Подключение ЖК-Монитора

void setup()
{
    pinMode(0, OUTPUT); // Выход на красную лампочку для авто
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT); // Выход на зеленую лампочку для пешехода
    pinMode(1, OUTPUT); // Выход на желтую лампочку для авто
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT); // Выход на красную лампочку для пешехода
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT); // Выход на зеленую лампочку для авто
    pinMode(5,INPUT);   // Выход на кнопку
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop()
{
    if (flag == digitalRead(5))
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
        lcd.setCursor(0 ,0);
        lcd.print("GREEN");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("RED");
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(0, LOW);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
        lcd.print("YELLOW");
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(4, LOW);
        digitalWrite(1, LOW);
        delay(200); 
        digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("RED");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print("GREEN");
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(2, LOW);
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
        lcd.print("YELLOW");
        delay(2000);
        digitalWrite(1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
        delay(200);
    }
}
```

Ответ программы в консоль:

```
5:39: error: stray '\315' in program  
5:40: error: stray '\276' in program  
28:19: error: stray '\315' in program  
28:20: error: stray '\276' in program  
35:20: error: stray '\315' in program  
35:21: error: stray '\276' in program  
43:17: error: stray '\315' in program  
43:18: error: stray '\276' in program  
45:19: error: stray '\315' in program  
45:20: error: stray '\276' in program  
50:22: error: stray '\315' in program  
50:23: error: stray '\276' in program  
6:1: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'void' In function 'void loop()':  
29:1: error: expected ';' before 'lcd'  
36:1: error: expected ';' before 'delay'  
44:1: error: expected ';' before 'lcd'  
46:1: error: expected ';' before 'delay'  
51:1: error: expected ';' before 'delay'  
exit status 1
```

Comment: на проблему с кодировкой похоже. создайте новый скетч, со своего вопроса скопируйте код, вставьте в ide и запустите заново

Comment: 1 - попробуйте удалить комментарии. 2 - возможно при копировании откуда-то в код попали какие-то лишние символы. Попробуйте скопировать код в стандартный блокнот, потом из него обратно. 3 - возможно некоторые буквы в коде заменены на похожие из кириллицы (например, русское С вместо латинского C).

Comment: Также выложите файл как есть на какой-нибудь обменник (хоть google disk), тогда можно будет посмотреть, что это за символы могли быть.

Comment: @insolor проверял в Word с функцией скрытых символов,вроде ничего не нашел,но возможно я слепой. Комментарии были добавлены поверх кода в этой теме. Некоторые строки из тех,что выдают ошибку переписал ручками,но к сожалению не помогло. Но возможно, я снова сделал проверку не так и где-то завалил код.
Ссылка на файл с кодом: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19JuGOND_fnSysKwtuR_f0ivcr7PIxKe8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Arduino IDE показывает на точки с запятой и на символ правее них. Консоль python у этой точки с запятой через `ord(';')` показывает код 894, а у обычной точки с запятой код 59. Введите вручную все точки с запятые в строках, на которые указывают ошибки.